# snowbabel extension <br /> tag displayed in frontend

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I've a problem with typo3 snowbabel extension. I need to insert a line break in frontend. In the manual, specified that  "if you want to have a line break visible in front end, you'll have to insert the HTML line break tag.
I've added it. But the html br tag displayed in frontend.Also the line break is not working.
Is there any configurations for this?

Thanks,

Arun Chandran

Comment: Did you check the xml file after updating using snowbabel? What is inserted there?

Comment: In getLL function html tags not rendering properly. Its actually a rule. So that this is not an issue.

Comment: So it's not an issue related to snowbabel, right?

Comment: Please try &lt;br /&gt; also!

Comment: No its not working. Displayed "&lt;br /&gt;" code in frontend.
Its not an issue related to snowbabel. But they have not mentioned about this in the manual

Answer (score 1):

This is just a handy quick solution to the problem. 
You can use `<section>` tags instead of "`<br/>`" tags. Even though their purpose might be different, it still gives the output.

OR

Just use `<br></br>` instead of `</br>`. Works fine.